# Plate trick demonstrating SO(3) not simply connected.

Tags: general-topology, rotations, fundamental-groups

I know there is another question about this, but I didn't find the answer adequate. How exactly does the plate trick (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plate_trick) show that $SO(3)$ isn't simply connected, but $SU(2)$ is? Which part of this is the path, and what's the homotopy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every piece of your arm has associated with it an element of $SO(3)$, which is the rotation required to move that part of your arm from the straight up position to where it is.  One end of your arm doesn't move (the end attached to your shoulder).  The other end (your hand) moves.  If $s$ is the arclength of your arm from the shoulder, then the map $s\mapsto R(s)$, where $R(s)$ is the element of $SO(3)$ representing the rotation of that part of the arm, is a continuous map from an interval to $SO(3)$.  After you have done the plate trick one time, your arm is in such an orientation that it doesn't contract to the constant map, but $R(s)$ at the ends of the intervals is the identity.  So it represents a non-contractible closed curve on $SO(3)$, that is, an element of the fundamental group of $SO(3)$ which is not homotopic to the identity.  But do the plate trick twice, and you are able to get your arm back to the constant map, showing that in the fundamental group of $SO(3)$ that this element squared is the identity.

Comment: If, at the end of the plate trick, your arm were untwisted, you'd have a homotopy showing that the path traced out by your hand is trivial in the fundamental group.  But I don't see how to run this argument backward.  Are you claiming that the because your arm is twisted, the path in question must be noncontractible?  It seems to me that all the twisted arm proves is that *one particular attempt* to demonstrate a contraction must fail.  But (without invoking some completely separate argument) how do we know there's not some other way to prove this loop is contractible?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking.  If you are asking whether "if it can be proved that the arm cannot be untwisted, then it can be proved that the path is noncontractible?" then I think the answer is "yes."  If you are asking "can we provide an easy to understand proof that the arm cannot be untwisted?" then the answer is "not to my knowledge."

Comment: Think of your arm representing a map from $p:[0,1] \to SO_3$, where $t$ is how far along the arm we are (in units so that the length of the whole arm is $1$), and $p(t)$ is the orientation of that piece of the arm.  Then any homotopy which takes $p$ to the trivial homotopy should, in principle, convert to a way to twist your arm so that it becomes untwisted.  (Fixing the endpoints corresponds to not allowing one to change the orientation of the shoulder or the hand.)

Comment: I am willing to grant that there's no way to untwist the arm (with the endpoints fixed).  My question was whether this proves that the path $p$ represents a nontrivial homotopy class.  (The converse was already clear to me.)  Your argument seems right (so much so that I no longer remember what I was failing to grasp).  Your argument seems right (so much so that I no longer remember why I had to ask.)  But --- it seems to rely only on the fact that it is possible to twist my arm into the plate trick's final position --- not on the plate trick itself. (CONTINUED)

Comment: (CONTINUED)  It seems that as long as I present my arm in that position, no matter what motion I used to get it there (and as long as I grant that it can't be untwisted), I've proved the existence of the nontrivial  homotopy class.  Then it's the untwisting on the second time around that proves the order of that class is exactly 2.  (This I do see.)  Have I missed anything?

Comment: Sounds right to me.

Comment: I've posted a followup question here:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1258645/the-plate-trick-and-so3