# The Plate Trick and $SO(3)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, homotopy-theory

This is a followup of sorts to [Plate trick demonstrating SO(3) not simply connected.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/736154/plate-trick-demonstrating-so3-not-simply-connected) .

Suppose I do the ``plate trick'' to demonstrate the existence of an order-2 element in $\pi_1(SO(3))$.  That is, I extend my arm, pretend that I've attached the standard orthogonal basis for ${\mathbb R}^3$ to each point along my arm, and make a circle with my hand, ending up with my fingertips restored to their original position and my arm twisted.

I've now constructed two different loops in $SO(3)$ --- the loop $Q$ traced out by my fingertips over time and the loop $P$ traced out by distance along my arm after the motion is completed.  I've always been a little confused about whether I'm supposed to focus on Q or on P.  They are related by square A below:

[image]

Now (writing [] for homotopy classes) we have:

Theorem 1:  [P]=[Q].  Proof:  Square A.

Theorem 2:  [P] is non-trivial.  Proof:  If there were a homotopy from P to the trivial loop, I could use it to untwist my arm without changing the orientation of my fingertips.  (I take it to be obvious that this is impossible).

Theorem 3:  [Q]+[Q] is trivial.  Proof:  Square A plus Square B.

These three theorems taken together prove that [Q] (or equivalently [P]) has order 2.  That is, we prove (Theorem 2) that [P] has order **at least** 2, we prove (Theorem 3) that [Q] has order **at most** 2, and then we invoke Theorem 1 to get the result.

So it appears that to get the desired result, one has to focus on both P and Q, and that it is insufficient to focus on just one of them.

My question is:  Is this correct?  In other words:  Can we prove directly (without mentioning [P]) that [Q] has order exactly 2, and/or can we prove directly (without mentioning [Q]) that [P] has order exactly 2?

Answer (score 1):

There are other versions of this trick, see for example the well produced video [Air on the Dirac Strings](https://www.evl.uic.edu/hypercomplex/html/dirac.html) and my own version which relates it to the [Projective Plane](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/outofline/motion.html#motion).

I think there is a serious point in the question. All these versions illustrate, in a way which can be made rigorous,  that a certain loop $a$ is such that $a^2$ is homotopic  to the identity; but they do not show that $a$ itself is not homotopic to the identity. For that it seems you do need the Seifert-van Kampen Theorem. If you are doing that, you might as well do the [many pointed version](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/topgpds.html), which gets the,  or, strictly speaking, a,  fundamental group of the circle, and much more, as well.